# I need to install Wireshark on my CentOS VM

Tags: centos, wireshark

I used the following commands to install the tool:

$ yum install gcc gcc-c++ bison flex libpcap-devel qt-devel gtk3-devel rpm-build libtool c-ares-devel qt5-qtbase-devel qt5-qtmultimedia-devel qt5-linguist desktop-file-utils

$ sudo yum install wireshark wireshark-qt

Getting following error:

wireshark
(wireshark:5032): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:34:42.462: cannot open display:

Comment: You might want to install xorg, or plasma, or dwm.

Comment: Wireshark is the GUI tool. If you want the CLI tool to capture packets, it is called “tshark”

Comment: Yes , that worked , Thanks